# VBS - how to get DOMAIN proxy settings for a machine?

Tags: vbscript, proxy, dns, registry

The following code in a VB Script file will allow me to get the proxy enabled flag on a machine.   For example, I do not have the proxy enabled on my machine, so it returns "0".

However, these are Windows Domain computers and in most cases I am getting back nothing - not 0, but a blank.

I am assuming this is because I have a domain policy that is enforcing the proxy settings (as ON).

SO, the question is how do I read that?   Is it a different registry key, or do I have to read something completely different like network settings somehow?

```
const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
    Set oReg=GetObject( _
   "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
strValueName = "ProxyEnable"
oReg.GetDWORDValue _
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If registry value `ProxySettingsPerUser` in key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` is 1, then the proxy is defined per user (i.e. it can be retrieved from the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` key).

If `ProxySettingsPerUser` is 0, then the proxy is defined for the whole computer (i.e. the proxy settings are stored in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`).

Comment: What if there is no ProxyEnable (or anything with the word proxy) in either place (and no ProxySettingsPerUser key) ?     On all my machines, none of them have the  ProxySettingsPerUser key and none have any proxy settings at the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE ... path you mention.

Comment: I may have found my answer.   We run Sophos anti-virus.   It looks like the proxy settings are being stored in  the local machine, software\sophos\savservice\sophosproxy.      It's not being pushed down by the sophos server or set in the sophos software, I personally have set the proxy settings for some of these in internet explorer connection settings.  So it seems sophos is doing something and intercepting the settings.